# weird firefox warning when loading video from a url

Tags: javascript, firefox

In the following screenshot below , you would see a dev screen of a site that is under development.

Video thumbnail is loaded and its HTTP 200, which is acceptable. But the weird thing is that video file is not HTTP 200. i believe this is something not right.

[image]

It even says in the console that "Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed.".  but actually you can see the video was being loaded in the screenshot.

Please help me to get rid of this weird behavior.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks odd, could you post a link to the page that produces this behavior so we can see it for ourselves too?

Comment: unfortunately this is on localhost, so unable to provide a link at this moment. i will try to host it outside and let you know.